# Receiving a 401 'truncated server' error when trying to add a Stripe API Key to UrlFetchApp in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, stripe-payments

I'm trying to [retrieve an invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/retrieve) in Google Sheets via the Stripe API and I'm using Google Apps Scripts to run my code. Here's the code I have:

```
function callNumbers() 
  {
    var url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/[unique_id]";
    var apiKey = "[api-key]";

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {"headers":{"[api-key]":apiKey}}); 
    var content = response.getContentText(); 
    Logger.log(response); 
    Logger.log(content);
 }
```

The Stripe invoice URL has a unique ID in the url above after /invoices/, representing the specific test invoice I want to retrieve.

I'm using a [test Stripe API key](https://stripe.com/docs/api/authentication), which begins with this before the unique API key code: `sk_test_`

The reference on the Stripe page looks like this:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/[unique_id] \
  -u sk_test_[api-key]:
```

The error message I receive looks like this:

```
Request failed for https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/[unique_id] returned code 401. Truncated server response: { "error": { "message": "You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 13, file "Code")
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with my code. I'm guessing it's something with the `"headers"` section but I don't know enough about APIs to know for sure. I'm using this test project in attempt to learn more about APIs.

Comment: I suspect your issue is whatever that headers section is doing.  You can either use Basic Auth or you can use Bearer Auth.  You're doing ~maybe basic?  It's not really clear.  I'd probably just change your header to be `Authorization : Bearer sk_test_xxx`.  I suspect that would look like this: `{"headers":{"Authorization" : "Bearer " + apiKey}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function getInvoiceObj(invoiceURL) {
  var content,options,response ,secret,url;

  secret = 'sk_test_ABC123';//sk_live_ABC123'

  url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/" + invoiceURL;

  options = {
    "method" : "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + secret
    },
    "muteHttpExceptions":true
  };

  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  content = response.getContentText(); 
  Logger.log(response); 
  Logger.log(content);
}
```

Comment: Hi Alan, that fixed my issue! Thanks so much! For anyone who reads this post in the future for reference, it looks like it worked for me without needing to use the apiKey in line five `url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/" + apiKey;`  Instead of using `+ apiKey` you can just use the unique invoice url which will look like `https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/in_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`